# Foursquare venue search API returns out-of-radius results

Tags: ios, objective-c, geolocation, foursquare

I've taken a picture at the `keizersgracht` in `Amsterdam`. I'm building a feature that, in the case that there is a strict match between the location of the photo and Foursquare venue, I include a location to where the photo was taken. Otherwise, I wish the result to be `nil`.

Documentation to the Foursquare API call I'm making can be found here: https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/search

Since I don't know what kind of venue the picture is taken at, I can't add a `query` parameter, which excludes `intent=match` from the options. As a workaround, I've chosen to use `intent=checkin` and add almost all `categoryId's` to the request.

My request now looks like this:

```
//latitude & longitude are taken as parameters to the method
NSString *clientId = @"redacted";
NSString *clientSecret = @"redacted";
NSString *version =@"20140806";
NSString *limit = @"1";
NSString *radius = @"1";
NSString *categoryId = @"4d4b7104d754a06370d81259,4bf58dd8d48988d1b4941735,4bf58dd8d48988d1b2941735,4bf58dd8d48988d1a8941735,4bf58dd8d48988d1ad941735,4d4b7105d754a06373d81259,4d4b7105d754a06374d81259,4d4b7105d754a06376d81259,4d4b7105d754a06377d81259,4d4b7105d754a06375d81259,4e67e38e036454776db1fb3a,4d4b7105d754a06378d81259,4d4b7105d754a06379d81259"; //almost all the cat id's

NSDictionary *venueResponse = [self getDataFrom:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?client_id=%@&client_secret=%@&v=%@&ll=%@,%@&m=foursquare&limit=%@&radius=%@&intent=checkin&categoryId=%@", clientId, clientSecret, version, lat, lng, limit, radius, categoryId]];
NSLog(@"%@",venueResponse);
```

The method `getDataFrom` is about making a simple GET request.

However, when I'm passing a location in the center of Amsterdam, I get out-of radius results, like this one: (snippet)

```
cc = NL;
                    city = Amsterdam;
                    country = Netherlands;
                    distance = 24;
                    formattedAddress =                     (
                        Amsterdam,
                        Netherlands
                    );
```

This is weird, since I specifically added a radius of 1.

What is it that might cause this and what can I do about it?

Comment: You're aware the distance and radius values are in meters ya?

Comment: I am. So that actually means that they're the same value..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend ditching the radius parameter. Your device has a location. Instead of constructing a request with such a small radius (it is very unlikely that your iPhone is going to have the accuracy of 1 meter in it's location) and so many categories, you could ask for likely nearby locations (which the intent=checkin does) and simply enumerate over the returned data to find the place that is the shortest distance away from your device's location (as @Acey mentions). You can calculate this yourself using the API provided in Core Location, or by using the distance returned on each compact venue. If you don't use a radius parameter, then you aren't required to include categoryIds or a query. (Also, because the accuracy of location on an iPhone can vary you will definitely have some cases to solve!) :)

Further, if the app is only for photos at one particular category of places (say, coffee shops) then requesting that categoryId in your GET request makes sense. Unless I am misunderstanding, it seems like you are including categoryIds just because you think you need to include a radius parameter, which I don't think is necessary.

If you want the "best" match for a particular user, you will need to allow the user to authenticate with their Foursquare account. Foursquare will then return the "best" match for a venue that is personalized to that user probably based on, at least, their checkin history.

Also, if you are persisting this data in your app and don't want to offer authentication to Foursquare, you could create your own algorithms on the device using the user's accumulated data in order to help decide what location a user is at when they take future photos.

Good luck building the app. Seems like a neat idea with some good challenges to think through.

Answer (score 1):

The distance value on the result is the distance from the center of that location. In the case of Amsterdam, the location is large enough that part of it is located within 1 mile of your location. Think of overlapping circles. The distance between the centers may be larger than 1, but the distance from your circle to any part of the location is, well, 0 actually.

I would guess the result set you get back contains multiple places. I would go through the results and choose the venue with the shortest distance, that should give you the most accurate venue.

Comment: what do you mean by 'circle', actually? I thought that was the radius I was setting..

Comment: You provide a search region by specifying a point and a radius, the components of a circle. That sample location you got back has area overlapping with that region so it is returned, even though the center of that location is further than 1m.

Comment: Ah okay, thanks. I actually don't want that. Do you know how to solve this issue with the current data? Can I somewhere specify the radius of the other location?

Comment: Actually, I wish the result to be `nil` if the center is out of radius. Do you maybe know a little workaround that I could pull off for `intent=match` maybe? I hate to use a simple `if` statement since foursquare does not return best match first.

Comment: Please read my question and the documentation a bit more carefully. I *do not* know the query. The only thing I know is the `ll`. Furthermore, let me quote the docs: `query and ll are the only required parameters for this intent, but matching also supports phone, address, city, state, zip, and twitter. `

Comment: @Acey Your answer is incorrect: he's not trying to query a specific location but wants to receive locations that are around a specific `ll`. I do not know how to solve this, sadly, but I do know that his question and the question you're answering are two completely different things.

Comment: @Andre you're right about my comment being incorrect. I removed the other answer. However, it was the comment that was incorrect, but THIS answer still would solve the problem.

Comment: (Repost, I removed the partial incorrect comment from before) I think looping through the results and determining the one with the smallest distance is a fairly simple operation. At least give it a try to see if you are getting the results you want.

Comment: @Acey I'm sorry but it's just simply not the result I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: I think it is unrealistic to expect just one perfect result when asking what venue am I located in if you are in fact at multiple venues. If you were at the White House, it is perfectly accurate to say you are at the White House, the Capital Mall, and Washington D.C. The distance to the White House would be the shortest so you should pick that, or else allow the user to decide like Facebook does.